# A numerical regarding relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, velocity

So the question goes, there is a river of width $w$ and there are two swimmers $A$ and $B$, both of whom swim at a velocity of $7.5km/h$ with respect to the river. The river is flowing at $2km/h$.

Swimmer A swims right across the river in a straight path and reaches point P.

Swimmer B swims perpendicular to the river flow so he drifts downstream till point Q. Then he walks till point P.

If they both reach point P at the same time, how fast does swimmer B walk?

I suppose one has to equate times like t1=t2+t3 and assuming any number for rearrange the equation for walking velocity. I got the answer as $34.27km/h$, can anyone please verify?

Also I think this combines a lot of concepts of vector math and relative velocity so I hope it can be open for future users?